# In context of CT, Is there some categorical depth to arithmetic beyond being a pedagogical tool for understanding CT?

Tags: category-theory

The analogy between arthimetic and CT concept is used ubiquitous by a book done one of the very founders of CT themself called Conceptual Mathematics. I found this quite profound and made a post paraphrasing what was written in one of those pages [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4730425/688539). Here is another example I found when reading about categorical sections:

> The first proposition may be regarded as an analog for maps to the observation that once we have multiplication and ‘reciprocals’ (numbers like x =} to solve equations like $3x=1$) we can then express the answers to more general division problems like $3x=5$ by $x= \frac{5}{3}$. The proposition says that if the single choice problem
>
> [image]
>
> has a solution( a section for f ) , then every choice problem
>
> [image]
> >
> involving this same $f$ has a solution

Is there a way to make this connection concrete?

Comment: The elements of a monoid (such as the multiplicative group of real numbers) can be viewed as the morphisms of [a category with only one object](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/907064). Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Does CT mean "category theory"? (guessing by the tag used)  My two cents are that it'd be better to type it: i've never seen that abbreviation used and there's no charge for characters.